# EF Core GroupBy-Sum LINQ generating Unexpected SQL

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ query:

```cs
var data = await _context.Answers
    .Where(q => q.Question != null)
    .GroupBy(q => q.Choice)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Data = g.Sum(q => q.Question.Weight)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

My tables are as follows:

```cs
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Choice? Choice { get; set; } # Has values 0, 1, 2 in db

    #region Associations

    public Guid? QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question? Question { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Question
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ushort Weight { get; set; }
}
```

The following SQL query is getting generated for the above LINQ query:

```sql
SELECT [a].[Choice] AS [Key],
       (
           SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CAST([t1].[Weight] AS int)), 0)
           FROM [Answers] AS [a0]
               LEFT JOIN [Questions] AS [t0]
                   ON [a0].[QuestionId] = [t0].[Id]
               LEFT JOIN [Questions] AS [t1]
                   ON [a0].[QuestionId] = [t1].[Id]
           WHERE ([t0].[Id] IS NOT NULL)
                 AND (
                         [a].[Choice] = [a0].[Choice]
                         OR (
                                ([a].[Choice] IS NULL)
                                AND ([a0].[Choice] IS NULL)
                            )
                     )
       ) AS [Data]
FROM [Answers] AS [a]
    LEFT JOIN [Questions] AS [t]
        ON [a].[QuestionId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE [t].[Id] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [a].[Choice]
```

NOTE:

- EF Core: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.2
- Database: SQL Server 2019

I don't get why a subquery is being generated for the SUM function. I expected the generated SQL to be something like the one given below.

```sql
SELECT [a].[Choice] AS [Key],
       COALESCE(SUM(CAST([t].[Weight] AS int)), 0) AS [Data]
FROM [Answers] AS [a]
    LEFT JOIN [Questions] AS [t]
        ON [a].[QuestionId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE [t].[Id] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [a].[Choice]
```

Is it possible to avoid the subquery in the generated SQL?

Comment: Are  your Answer and Question classes scaffolded from customer DB or are you are designing them by yourself? Because first of all, Question must have GUID primary key in your case, second, looks like you've designed  your one-to-one relationship wrong and EF can't understand that fact.

Comment: I replaced the names of the tables and changed the data type of the ID fields to int to simplify the question (and missed some places). Actually, all Ids fields are Guids. I'll edit the question right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move out navigation propery usage from aggregation function

```cs
var query = 
    from a in _context.Answers
    where a.Question != null
    group new { a.Question.Weight } by a.Choice into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key,
        Data = g.Sum(q => q.Weight)
    };

var data = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I believe this query also generated the same SQL as the one I gave above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i Think you Query is inner join (left + not null Question).It is better to use Join and change the data type of the question Id from the answer (because Id table question is int but questionId from answer is guid)

Change DataType

```
 public int? QuestionId { get; set; }
```

If you don't change the data type  question Id, an additional query will be performed on the join itself

```
LEFT JOIN [Question] AS [q] ON [a].[QuestionId1] = [q].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Question] AS [q0] ON [q].[Id] = [q0].[Id]
```

If you select the grouping type of the table, it will group on all the fields Choice, it is better to specify the field

```
LEFT JOIN [Choice] AS [c] ON [a].[ChoiceId] = [c].[Id]
GROUP BY [c].[Id], [c].[Value]
```

Final  query:

```
  var query = context.Answer
        .Join(
            context.Question,
            Answer => Answer.QuestionId,
            Question => Question.Id,
            (Answer,Question) => new { Answer, Question }
        ).Where(q => q.Question != null)
    .GroupBy(q => q.Answer.Choice.Value)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Data = g.Sum(q => q.Question.Weight)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Query:

```
SELECT [c].[Value] AS [Key], COALESCE(SUM(CAST([q].[Weight] AS int)), 0) AS [Data]
FROM [Answer] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [Question] AS [q] ON [a].[QuestionId] = [q].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Choice] AS [c] ON [a].[ChoiceId] = [c].[Id]
GROUP BY [c].[Value]
```

Comment: The query with the LINQ Join operator works perfectly. However, I'm also looking to understand why my query performs a subquery with two LEFT JOINS. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is related to the sum

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but because you didn't use Join. And in sum, you said that it comes from the question table cause of use subqueries